# Array size as a logarithm

Tags: c++, arrays

Why won't C++ allow this as an array size?

```
const int SIZE = ceil(log10(pow(2., 1000)));
int arr[SIZE];
```

For those that are interested, this is for problem 16 on ProjectEuler.  I'm trying to declare an array to hold each digit of the number 2^1000 and this is my way of finding how many elements I need.

Comment: error C2057: expected constant expression

Comment: I am able to run the code: http://ideone.com/WU28aF

Comment: Compilation issues aside: log10(pow(2.,1000)) == 1000*log10(2.) (modulo the precision of C++ doubles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't allow it because the right side of `=` is not a constant expression, which is required for `SIZE` to be a constant expression. Now `const int` merely means it's a read-only integer object.

```
const int SIZE = ceil(log10(pow(2., 1000)));
```

Use a dynamic array instead, such as `std::vector`.

Or you can take your calculator and hardcode the value - it's approximately 301.03, by the way :)

Comment: Is it not constant because the log and ceil functions might evaluate to different values depending on rounding?

Comment: @David That, and because of the fact `ceil` and `log10` are not declared `constexpr`. Which they can't be anyway, since they're from C library.

Answer (score 0):

even though you use the const qualifier for `SIZE`, this only means you have a read-only variable, and it's value will not be known at compile time. Because of the function calls `ceil, log10, pow` the value of SIZE will only be know at runtime  so the compiler cannot statically allocate SIZE bytes because SIZE it know yet known.

So, either dynamically allocate memory or compute the value yourself :)